# hebrew characters don't show in "UTF-8 without BOM" only "UTF-8"

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

My html document starts as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
אבגד
```

If I encode my document as `UTF-8`, it appears correctly in the browser.  If I encode as `UTF-8 without BOM` (which I understand is more standard) I get unusual characters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the web server specify the encoding in the content-type header? Does this value change?

Comment: Try converting your Hebrew text [here](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php). I have no idea if it will work, but there's no harm in trying!

Comment: @JoshLee where do I find that?

Comment: @SankarshMakam I need to be able to show information that is coming from my database, so I would like to have a solution where the text itself does not need to be converted.

Comment: @pppp In Chrome or Firefox, press F12 and go to Network, reload the page, click on the resource, and find the Response headers.

Comment: Ok, sorry! Didn't know that. But still can't you store it encoded or will that fail due to user input!

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks.  `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`.  How do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server is declaring that the encoding is `ISO-8859-1`, and the browser is respecting that. Ironically enough, using a byte order mark sends a **stronger** signal to the browser that the encoding must actually be UTF-8. (The exact reason for this is [complicated and boring](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding).)

Fixing your web server depends on what the server is. If this is a static resource on disk served by Apache httpd, then something like `AddCharset UTF-8 .html` will add the header.

If this resource is served dynamically, then you should make sure you add the proper HTTP headers when producing the response, something like `self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')` for Python's basic http server.

Comment: Thank you. Should I still be including the charset in the html or is that unnecessarily redundant?

Comment: According to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#character-encoding-declaration, one is required. Using both could be considered redundant, but might allow your text editor to use the correct encoding, for instance.